# How to prevent other application with administrator rights from disabling hooks registered through JNativeHook?

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, jnativehook

I have a Java application running on Windows that registers mouse and keyboard hooks through the JNativeHook API (https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook). My problem is that they are getting disabled by an external application with administrator rights.

I have done loads of debugging and the application is only able to do this with administrator rights, and I need the application in administrator and mouse hooks to work together. I found out that if 2 applications both have administrator privileges, they both cannot disable each other's hooks, which is perfect, but that's not the case for me.

I can only think of 2 ways of fixing this problem, both of which I do not know how to do:

- Find a way to run Java in administrator (probably wouldn't work)
- Find/make a method in JNativeHook to make the hooks administrator enforced

  ```
      GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
      GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new MouseListener());
      GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new KeyListener());
  ```

MouseListener and KeyListener are two different classes that handle the mouse and keyboard events (not relevant to issue, but thought I'd throw it in).

How can I prevent my JNativeHook hooks from being disabled while the external application is running?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: did you get it dude ?